# No Accessor registered. Universal Tween Engine

Tags: android, imageview, tween, universal

I created the following accessor in order to add a simple tween to an imageview's position. I'm using a RelativeLayout.

```
public class ImageViewAccessor implements TweenAccessor<ImageView> {

     public static final int X = 1;
     public static final int Y = 2;
     public static final int XY = 3;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public int getValues(ImageView target, int tweenType, float[] returnValues) {
         switch (tweenType) {
             case X: returnValues[0] = target.getX(); return 1;
             case Y: returnValues[0] = target.getY(); return 1;
             case XY:
                 returnValues[0] = target.getX();
                 returnValues[1] = target.getY();
                 return 2;
             default: assert false; return 0;
         }
     }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
     public void setValues(ImageView target, int tweenType, float[] newValues) {    
         switch (tweenType) {
             case X: target.setX(newValues[0]); break;
             case Y: target.setY(newValues[1]); break;
             case XY:
                 target.setX(newValues[0]);
                 target.setY(newValues[1]);
                 break;
             default: assert false; break;
         }
     }
}
```

I'm registering the accessor using the following code:

```
Tween.registerAccessor(ImageViewAccessor.class, new ImageViewAccessor());
Tween.to(logo, ImageViewAccessor.Y, 1f).target(50).start();
```

But I'm getting a crash "No TweenAccessor was found for the target" on the `Tween.to(logo, ImageViewAccessor.Y, 1f).target(50).start();` so I have 2 questions.

- Can I use this framework to add simple tweens to an imageview (I want the image to hover about 5 px up then 5 px down)?
- Also, Why is this error showing, if I have registered an accessor just before calling the function?

EDIT:  Also,  `ImageView.getX()` and `ImageView.getY()` are present in api level 11. But i dont know if should use them or i should use `layaoutparamenters.topMargin`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this question is pretty old, but I'll answer anyway for people searching this later.

The error is in

```
Tween.registerAccessor(ImageViewAccessor.class, new ImageViewAccessor());
```

The first parameter is the class that you want to access, and the second one is the Accessor that should be used to access that class.

Sou you wrote that you want to access the ImageViewAccessor, but actually you want to access the ImageView class using the ImageViewAccessor.

It should be like this:

```
Tween.registerAccessor(ImageView.class, new ImageViewAccessor());
```

Comment: hii @dermetfan I have a question . Is there any limit for tmx file in libgdx? I have 800 * 18 size . camera is set to 30 *80 and set to orthographictilemaprenderer . but sometimes player on jumping unable to collide with layer and fall. Sometime jumps too high. any suggestion..

Comment: The map size is not limited and I doubt it is in relation to your problem. I cannot say anything given just this little information though.